# Implementing DRY Forms

Tags: forms, dry, playframework-2.0

Getting into Play 2.0, overall, blown away, great stuff.

Anyway, wondering how one can achieve DRY forms in Play? If you look at the create & edit examples in the [Computer Database Sample](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/scala/computer-database/app/views), you'll see that the form elements are repeated. With just 4 fields (in the sample form), no big deal, but when you're dealing with large, complex forms and/or handling many CRUD models, the duplication becomes a bigger maintenance issue.

On the binding end ( `form.bindFromRequest` and `form.fill(Foo)` ), the implementation is so elegant for create/edit operations; is there a corresponding solution in the template layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

k, here's what I came up with to handle a signup, renewal scenario:

```
// views.subscription.signup.scala.html
@(_form: Form[com.company.model.Subscription], target: play.api.mvc.Call)
@import helper._

@cart("Foobar Registration") {
  <h1>Join Foobar Today!</h1>
  @form(action = target, 'id -> "subscriptionForm", 'class -> "form-horizontal") {
    @fields(_form) // include formfields
  }
}

// views.subscription.fields.scala.html
@(_form: Form[com.company.model.Subscription])
@import helper._

@inputText(field = _form("firstName"), '_label-> "First Name*", 'class-> "required")
@inputText(field = _form("lastName"), '_label-> "Last Name*", 'class-> "required")
....
```

Then, for renewal, just create the same shell as signup.scala.html, but with renewal title and header text.

Same principle applies for any shared create/edit form state.